# Javascript replace global parameters in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have developed a slider based on Foundation in JS. It has some initial configs and functions. One instance of the slider works, but when adding another slider to the page the global configs get overwritten and the first slider controlls the second.

Here's part of the code:

```
  Foundation.libs.slider = {
    name: 'slider',
    version: '0.1.0',
    settings: {
        callback: function () {
        },
        active_class: "active"
    },
    stat: '',
    windowWidth: '',
    slide: '',
    slideWidth: '',
    slideCount: '',
    slidesVisible: 0,
    bullets: '',
    bulletsHtml: '',
    bulletsCount: 0,
    bullet: '',
    init: function (scope, method, options) {
        this.bindings(method, options);
    },
    events: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.S('[data-stats]', this.scope).each(function () {
            self.slider($(this)); 
        });
    },
```

As I understand, each [data-stats] is overwriting the settings.
How do I make the global settings part of each object?

I have little knowledge of JS and would be very gratefull of your help.

Comment: With "most" jQuery plugins, the class instance is normally stored in `data('pluginname')`, on the DOM element, so they can be re-accessed per element. I imagine foundation would have a similar requirement under the hood. I will defer to any `foundation` experts though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to initialize sliders independently in separate instances and control the object you are instanced. For example:

```
    var slider1 = new Slider();
    var slider2 = new Slider();
    slider1.init();
    slider2.init();
```

Obviously, you need methods to init separately, and you can return selector or entire object.

Good luck